# Check if a pandas csv chunk contains a string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading a huge csv file with pandas and I would like to filter lines by some criterias, one of them is checking if a column's values contains a certain substring.
Here is what I did :

```
df = pd.concat(( [chunk[chunk['Device Pool'].find(devicePool) != -1] for chunk in pd.read_csv(sourceFile, iterator=True, chunksize=10**4)]))
```

But I got "KeyError : False"

EDIT :

[image]

From this CSV in want to generate a new one that contains only rows which "Device Pool" value contains for example "SRST"

Comment: can you provide df.head(10) output?. And what substring you consider?

Comment: Please post a sample input of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: Just edited my post

Comment: Can you change this line `[chunk[chunk['Device Pool'].find(devicePool) != -1]` to `[chunk[chunk['Device Pool'].str.contains("SRST")]` and see what you get?